# Entropy and partition function for system with normally-distributed microstates

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, partition-function

I'm looking at an example system which has a very large number of microstates (effectively infinite - not possible to enumerate exhaustively, but possible to sample from).  The energies of the microstates however are drawn from a normal distribution with some average energy and standard deviation of the energy.

What is the partition function for a system like this expressed in terms of the average energy and standard deviation of the energy?  What is the entropy?

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but I think you are saying that you have a specific functional form $\rho(E)$ for the distribution of states with energy? Is that correct?

Comment: @hft Yes, exactly.  If you draw a large sample of microstates and plot a histogram of the total energies, it has a straightforward ρ(E) that converges to the normal distribution as the sample size gets larger